# JPA Query pobbility

Tags: jpa

The below sql query is working well at MySQL browser.

SELECT c.* from (select c1 from City c1) c.

But if I tried the same query at my jpql 1.0 createquery, it denotes error.Is it possible to write the same query in jpa too. I dont need any alternative query for the constraint. I want only the possiblity of the above query. If it is, then tell me how?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String%29), createQuery takes [JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html) query as an argument. It is expected to end up with error, when providing SQL query as an argument to method that expects JQPL query.

If you want to execute native SQL queries, that can be done via [createNativeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I know about using native query. But I need a solution only on either query or namedquery and not on native query.